# How do I map ctrl x ctrl o to ctrl space in terminal vim?

Tags: vim, mapping, omnicomplete

After searching a bit on the net it seems that I can't map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to anything/alot. Is there a way to do it today, what I found was usually 2 years old.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I've run into the same issue, the short answer is yes you can, and not only in the gui version. Adding this on you `.vimrc` is enough:

```
inoremap <C-Space> <C-x><C-o>
inoremap <C-@> <C-Space>
```

Comment: I know this is _really_ nitpicking, but I would consider using `inoremap` instead of just `imap`, since the former will make sure that any messing around you do later won't change these settings.  But, really, that's overcautious overkill.

Comment: For me it's working just `inoremap <C-@> <c-x><c-o>` (on linux)

Comment: I tried this again, and in fact... it just worked with `inoremap <C-Space> <C-x><C-o>` and works fine in terminal vim and gvim. Now if I add the last part, it stops working. Trying with an "empty" vimrc (`vim -u NONE`), none of the combinations work. So I guess some configuration **has** to be set in your `.vimrc` (which one is something that I don't know).

Comment: In my experience, using `inoremap` for these 2 mappings worked on Mac but not Linux. I changed them to `imap` and now it works on both platforms. So: `:imap <C-@> <C-Space>` and `:imap <C-Space> <C-x><C-o>`

Comment: I can't get this working properly in GVim on Windows. It keeps inserting a space and so defaults to the first autocompletion

Comment: Could you add a link to the relevant docs of `<C-@>`? I've been searching but can't find anything. I'm curious what this answer actually does. I'd love to have a deeper understanding of this.... nevermind. Answered by @romainl. It can be found in `:h CTRL-@`. Seems it was too easy!

Comment: Please guys let's make this answer clearer : `inoremap <C-Space> ...` alone works in GUI, and in terminals, `<C-Space>` is interpreted as `<C-@>` so one must remap it _recursively_  to <C-Space> for the first instruction to be taken into account, with `imap <C-@> <C-Space>` ; @Pablo please change the second `inoremap` to `imap` in your answer.

Answer (score 26):

The problem seems to be that Terminal.app doesn't interpret `<C-Space>` correctly and Vim understands it as `<C-@>` which is a built-in mapping (`:help CTRL-@`).

Maybe you could go with something like the following in your .vimrc:

```
if !has("gui_running")
    inoremap <C-@> <C-x><C-o>
endif
```

which seems to work, here, but I don't like the idea of overriding built-ins like that.

Instead you should try with `<Leader>` (`:help leader`), it gives you huge possibilities for defining your own custom mappings and (depending on the `mapleader` you choose) won't interfere with OS/app specific shortcuts/limitations and hence be more portable.

With this in my .vimrc:

```
let mapleader=","
inoremap <leader>, <C-x><C-o>
```

I just hit `,,` to complete method names.

Comment: It is not only Terminal.app who outputs NULL when you type `<C-Space>`. I won't be surprised if I find out that it is written in some standart: at least urxvt and konsole also do this thing.

Answer (score 6):

The nitpicker broke pablox solution. The crux of the solution was just about remapping. So when you disable remapping, it cannot work.
If you really want to throw in a `noremap`, this is what it looks like:

```
inoremap <expr><C-space> neocomplete#start_manual_complete()
imap <C-@> <C-Space>
```

What will **not** work: `inoremap <C-@> <C-Space>` 'cause the `<C-Space>` part will not be remapped itself.

Comment: For me results in:
`E117: Unknown function: neocomplete#start_manual_complete
E15: Invalid expression: neocomplete#start_manual_complete()`

Comment: @user2609980 you need to map to a function that is available in your setup. the function I used as an example was taken from my personal setup.

Answer (score 4):

- Have you tried `:inoremap <c-space> <c-x><c-o>` ?
- Does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> do anything when you type in insert mode? Is `omnifunc` set?

Comment: This was the solution for me on MacOS 12, in iterm2, in Tmux, with a brew-installed Vim 8.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code to `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Ctrl-Space for completions. Heck Yeah!
inoremap <expr> <C-Space> pumvisible() \|\| &omnifunc == '' ?
        \ "\<lt>C-n>" :
        \ "\<lt>C-x>\<lt>C-o><c-r>=pumvisible() ?" .
        \ "\"\\<lt>c-n>\\<lt>c-p>\\<lt>c-n>\" :" .
        \ "\" \\<lt>bs>\\<lt>C-n>\"\<CR>"
imap <C-@> <C-Space>
```

Source: https://coderwall.com/p/cl6cpq

Comment: I think <lt> is html tag which means '<' symbol

Comment: Disregard my edition. I think is wrong. There should be a cancel edit option.

Answer (score 2):

To accommodate both Windows and Linux I applied this to `~/.vimrc`

```
if has("unix")
  inoremap <C-@> <c-x><c-o>
elseif has("win32")
  inoremap <C-Space> <c-x><c-o>
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I had better results with this set of mappings across all modes on Mac OS. Have not tested Windows or Linux.

I don't understand how the excepted answer is supposed to work in terminal mode.

```
inoremap <C-space>   <ESC>
vnoremap <C-space>   <ESC>
cnoremap <C-space>   <C-c>
" When in terminal, <C-Space> gets interpreted as <C-@>
imap     <C-@>       <C-space>
vmap     <C-@>       <C-space>
cmap     <C-@>       <C-space>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, using `inoremap` with the correct key for your term (as discovered using [i_Ctrl_v](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V)) should work. I will add to this another possible cause for problems with insert mode mappings: *paste mode*. As the [docs state](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27paste%27):

> ```
>     When the 'paste' option is switched on (also when it was already on):
>            - mapping in Insert mode and Command-line mode is disabled
> ```

This may seem irrelevant, but this very thing tripped me up trying to get a similar `inoremap` binding to work in Vim 8.2. I had `set paste` in my .vimrc, and had to chop it up with `:finish` statements (as [recommended in [the vim faq](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5)) to isolate the line causing the problem.