# What Does CTRL+Space Do in Vim?

Tags: vim

I've been looking for a while, but I can't seem to find any documentation on this key-command. Just by playing around, it seems that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> inserts the text that was typed in the last insert-mode session.

However, is something more subtle going on? What exactly does this key-command do in vanilla Vim?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`<C-Space>` doesn't do anything in any mode by default. Try `:verbose map <c-space>` to see where it is mapped to do what you see.

*edit*

I somehow forgot about [that previous answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7725796/546861):

When you press `<C-Space>`, the terminal sends an ambiguous signal to Vim which interprets it as `<Nul>`. Because `<Nul>` is usually represented as `<C-@>`, Vim acts as if you actually pressed `<C-@>` and tries to insert the previously inserted text.

Note that this issue is not present in GVim/MacVim.

Comment: Oh! Interesting. I must have something in my `.vimrc` that I wasn't aware of. Thanks!

Comment: @CaseyFalk You might want to also check `:verbose imap <c-space>`

Comment: Interestingly `map`, `nmap`, and `imap` each report, "No mapping found." o.0

Comment: Hmmm... this link also seems to argue that c-space *does* do something: http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/editors/vim-ctrl-space.html . I checked my `.vimrc` and I have no additional mappings. I'll keep exploring...

Comment: @CaseyFalk, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7725796/546861) to a previous question.

Comment: Ahh! And lo-and-behold: "Insert previously inserted text and stop insert."

Comment: So, by default the key combo <C-Space> actually is understood by Vim as <C-@> -- which inserts previously inserted text (as I was experiencing). Awesome! Thanks @romainl. So <C-Space> *does* do something.

Comment: No, `<C-@>` does something. `<C-Space>` is badly interpreted by the terminal which sends bogus info to Vim which does what it can with what it gets. Vim doesn't receive `<C-Space>` at all so `<C-Space>` does nothing and is not used for any command in Vim by default.