# Ctrl-Space is unexpectedly detaching me from docker container

Tags: docker

I changed the default "detachKeys" value in config.json for Docker to "ctrl-@". However, hitting `ctrl-space` is causing me to detach. Why is ctrl-space detaching and how do I stop this from happening? And what is a good value for detachKeys? I frequently attach to the container and use vim to edit so I want to avoid conflicts with any vim key bindigns.

I'm using iterm2 on a mac.

Comment: Same issue reported here: https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/2339

Answer (score 0):

I changed the value of `detachKeys` to `ctrl-^` for now. That seems to solve the problem (for now) and can now use `ctrl-space` within vim without issue.

This answer may shed some light on why `ctrl-space` was detaching: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24983736/1641112 (however, detaching wasn't just happening in vim and was happening on the command line as well).