# How do you type <C-x><C-o> in Vim?

Tags: vim, go

What keys do `<C-x><C-o>` represent in Vim? My goal is to get autocompletions working for Golang.

I've installed this plugin and have the syntax highlighting working.

https://github.com/fatih/vim-go

The readme says that, "Autocompletion is enabled by default via `<C-x><C-o>`", but I don't know which keys to press.

Comment: It should be those keys, considering they are mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/q/7722177/6309

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's Ctrl+X, Ctrl+O. This combination is used in Vim for omnicompletion. Type `:h omnifunc` or `:h ft-go-omni` (I presume) for more information.

Comment: when i use this key combination, in insert mode, the window appaears , and first entry gets selected automatically and inserted.

Answer (score 1):

- go is executable?

  do you add path to golang into $PATH?
- vim-go is loaded?

  if you are using vim-plug or pluggable interface for plugins, you should have vim-go in ~/.vim/bundle
- are you editing go file?

  check `:set ft?` is `go`

Answer (score 0):

Do u execute ":GoInstallBinaries" in the vim?

And the bin path is add?

ps:

The default keybind is complex,

I recommend using [neocomplete.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) by Shougo and add follows on the [base configuration](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim#configuration-examples):

```
let g:neocomplete#sources#omni#input_patterns.go = '\h\w*\.\?'
inoremap <silent> <CR> <C-r>=<SID>my_cr_function()<CR>
function! s:my_cr_function()
    return pumvisible() ? neocomplete#close_popup() : "\<CR>"
endfunction
inoremap <expr><TAB>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"
```