# mapping of control and shift key not working in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I tried to map Ctrl and Shift key with spacebar in VIM (not GVIM)  normal mode, but seems to be not working for me , Here are my mappings :

```
nmap <C-Space> :nohlsearch<CR>
nmap <S-Space> :w<CR>
```

Other keys got mapped in normal mode & getting expected results but Ctrl & Shift doesn't mapping with other keys. Could anyone know this reason ? .

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Terminal.app? If so, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722177/how-do-i-map-ctrl-x-ctrl-o-to-ctrl-space-in-terminal-vim.

Comment: `<S-Space>` can't be mapped but `<C-Space>` is `<C-@>` in CLI Vim.

Comment: THanks guys this is working !

Answer (score 1):

Control (`Ctrl`) and Shift are *modifier* keys.  Unless you have radically changed your keyboard configuration, those keys do nothing unless you press at the same time a non-modifier key.  Likewise, pressing two modifiers at the same time without a non-modifier key does nothing.

That said, most of the keys on a terminal can be modified.  Due to the way things evolved back in the 1970s / 1980s, not all of the modified keys differ.  For instance, it is common to have both of these sending an ASCII NUL (0):

```
control space
control @
```

That is because originally the control key acted to suppress all but the low-order 5 bits of an 8-bit character.  Space is 32, and `@` is 64 in ASCII.

Further reading:

- [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)